# No echo output for PHP class_exists even though the class in on the page

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a message to display if a class is present, not sure if I've got the right idea with this or not but it doesn't appear to be showing anything even though the class is there on the page.

```
<?php if (class_exists('quote-me')): ?>
<?php echo $this->__('View Quotation'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Can someone let me know if I'm on the right track.

Comment: is the class in the same file or a different one?? if it is in a diff file, is the file included??? And I dont exactly understand why you need to use `<?php ?>` for everyline when you can just use it for the block of statements...

Comment: What is `$this` is pointing to?

Comment: You're not thinking about CSS classes here, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`class_exists()`](http://php.net/class_exists) only checks if the class has been defined, not if you currently have an instance of that class.  You could have the `quote-me` class defined and in scope, triggering the `if` block, but that by itself doesn't mean you have a valid instance of that class.

Assuming that `$this->__('View Quotation');` works if you have an instance, then the fact that it's not working could be an indication that you actually don't have an instance of the `quote-me` class in scope.

Answer (score 1):

from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) :

> This function checks whether or not the given class has been defined.

So, yes you are on the right track.

```
<?php if(class_exists('my_class_name')){
      // do something
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If this code isn't within the actual class then you should refer to the object by variable name which you assign to it at declaration/initialization, rather than `$this`.
For example,

```
    $test = new quote-me
if (class_exists('quote-me')) 
{
     echo $test->__('View Quotation'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should using `class_exists(some_class, false)` to prevent autoload...

Answer (score 0):

Yes class_exists is the right function (if this is your question)